# usb_cam installation on ubuntu and default launch file

Tags: roslaunch, usb-cam, ubuntu, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I installed ros-jade-usb-cam with apt-get and then made a "sudo dpkg -L ros-jade-usb-cam" which generated the following files:

/opt
/opt/ros
/opt/ros/jade
/opt/ros/jade/include
/opt/ros/jade/include/usb_cam
/opt/ros/jade/include/usb_cam/usb_cam.h
/opt/ros/jade/lib
/opt/ros/jade/lib/libusb_cam.so
/opt/ros/jade/lib/usb_cam
/opt/ros/jade/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node
/opt/ros/jade/lib/pkgconfig
/opt/ros/jade/lib/pkgconfig/usb_cam.pc
/opt/ros/jade/share
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/cmake
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/cmake/usb_camConfig.cmake
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/cmake/usb_camConfig-version.cmake
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/launch
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/launch/usb_cam-test.launch
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/package.xml
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ros-jade-usb-cam
/usr/share/doc/ros-jade-usb-cam/changelog.Debian.gz

and then I launch

rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node

and the image launches.

Where is the default .launch file, I created a usb_cam.launch file under ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib and I can launch roslaunch usb_cam.launch and it will work. (however when only I am in ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib directory.

I previously installed usb_cam on this computer from source, and everything was working fine - so the real question is:

when we install usb_cam tru ubuntu package system, where do we put the usb_cam.launch file?

Best regards,
C.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227931/usb_cam-installation-on-ubuntu-and-default-launch-file/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be ugly but you could drop another launch file alongside this one:

```
/opt/ros/jade/share/usb_cam/launch/usb_cam-test.launch
```

And then `roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam.launch`.

https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam/blob/develop/launch/usb_cam-test.launch

But really you should have a catkin package that contains your custom usb_cam.launch like `catkin_ws/src/my_package/launch/usb_cam.launch`, and then make sure to fill in the CMake commands to get it get installed if you are sourcing catkin_ws/install/setup.bash instead of devel/setup.bash, and then `roslaunch my_package usb_cam.launch` should work.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-08-24**:
Hey Lukasw

I tried a similar command in order to achieve this result.

```
 source /opt/ros/kinetic/share/usb_cam/launch/usb_cam-test.launch
```

However, error message

```
 bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/share/usb_cam/launch/usb_cam-test.launch: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'newLine
```

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-08-24**:
I apologize if it is a silly doubt. I am a newbie in ROS.
ROS- Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-24**:
You can't source a launch file, use roslaunch instead.

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-08-25**:
Thank you so much, that works perfectly.

Just one more question. If I need to change the default camera to be an external USB camera and not my integrated webcam. what changes do I need to make?

```
<param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
```

I changed the launch file this way, doesnt work.

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-08-25**:
edit. It works as per this
[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/197651/how-to-install-a-driver-like-usb_cam/)

However then I need to cd into the launch directory and then run roslaunch. It doesn't work if I run the command you mentioned. Any idea what could be the reason.

Thanks in advance